# Running Celery Flower behind Ambassador/Envoy reverse proxy

Tags: celery, envoyproxy, flower, ambassador

I am trying to route to a flower server from an [emissary/ambassador](https://github.com/emissary-ingress/emissary) proxy with a root path different from `/`. Under the hood this is just an envoy front proxy.

There is an [example](https://github.com/mher/flower/blob/master/examples/nginx.conf) of running celery flower behind nginx, but I am unable to replicate the same thing with ambassador.

My ambassador Mapping object is

```
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
generation: 16
host: strand.dev.REDACTED.info
kind: Mapping
metadata_labels:
  ambassador_crd: strand-flower.front-proxy-internal
name: strand-flower
namespace: front-proxy-internal
prefix: /flower/
regex_rewrite:
  pattern: ^/flower/(.*)$
  substitution: /\1
service: http://strand-flower.default.svc.cluster.local:80
```

Which ends in an envoy configuration of

```
{
  "match": {
    "case_sensitive": true,
    "headers": [
      {
        "exact_match": "strand.dev.REDACTED.info",
        "name": ":authority"
      }
    ],
    "prefix": "/flower/",
    "runtime_fraction": {
      "default_value": {
        "denominator": "HUNDRED",
        "numerator": 100
      },
      "runtime_key": "routing.traffic_shift.cluster_http___strand_flower_default_svc-0"
    }
  },
  "route": {
    "cluster": "cluster_http___strand_flower_default_svc-0",
    "priority": null,
    "regex_rewrite": {
      "pattern": {
        "google_re2": {
          "max_program_size": 200
        },
        "regex": "^/flower/(.*)$"
      },
      "substitution": "/\\1"   <<< Is this supposed to be escaped?
    },
    "timeout": "3.000s"
  }
}
```

This results in the static assets not being served

[image]

However, it looks like the path is not actually being rewritten because I need to go to
`$HOSTNAME/flower/flower/` to get to the root, or to `$HOSTNAME/flower/flower/task` to get to the task part of the dashboard.

The flower server is started with `--url_prefix=flower` per the documentation [here](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#url-prefix).

How do I get flower to work behind Ambassador?

**nginx example**

```
server {
    location /flower/static {
        alias  /the/path/to/flower/static;
    }
    location /flower {
        rewrite ^/flower/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5555;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in-case anyone comes across this.

The problem is that you don't want the rewrite rule listed in the documentation.

You want an ambassador mapping that looks like this

```
---
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind:  Mapping
metadata:
  name:  strand-flower
spec:
  prefix: /flower/
  rewrite: /flower/
  service: http://strand-flower.default.svc.cluster.local:80
  host: "strand.dev.REDACTED.info"
```

The docs recommend that you rewrite rewrite `/flower/thing/` -> `/thing/`, but instead you just want to pass the path through and make sure to set `--url_prefix=flower` when starting your flower server.